# Codeigniter: Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm using CodeIgniter's Active Record Classes and I'm retrieving an error using the following code:

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->order_by("id");
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$this->db->from("atoms");
$this->db->join("atommeta", "atommeta.atom_id = atoms.atom_id");

$query  = $this->db->get();
```

It produces this error:

```
Error Number: 1052

Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous

SELECT * FROM (`atoms`) JOIN `atommeta` ON `atommeta`.`atom_id` = `atoms`.`atom_id` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 10

Filename: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/atom/models/atom_model.php

Line Number: 197
```

Line 197: `$query  = $this->db->get();`

Any ideas as to why? It seems to be something to do with the `order_by`

Comment: Because the column name `'id'` is ambiguous... ... ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error means that you are trying to order by a column name that is used in more than one table.  Update your `order_by` statement with the name of the table that has the column you want to order by.  For example:

```
$this->db->order_by('atoms.id');
```

Comment: Leave it so that others who run into the same problem will have a solution :)

Comment: Not sure why others are answering when it's already been answered.

Comment: @Brogrammer If you look at the time of when answers were posted, you could see that they're very close each other. Personally, I answered because I got notification of an already posted answer when mine was complete and I was about to hit the submit button. Nobdisd's answer, instead, comes exactly 15 secs before mine, it could be easily said that we answered at the same time. So, " why other are answering", told 9 minutes after the last answer, it's a strange question

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is an `id` column in both your `atommeta` and `atoms` tables. Because you are joining these tables you will need to specify what column you want to order by.

You will want

```
$this->db->order_by("atoms.id");
```

or

```
$this->db->order_by("atommeta.id");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should specify which table that 'id' belogns to.

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("atoms");
$this->db->join("atommeta", "atommeta.atom_id = atoms.atom_id");
```

pick one:

```
$this->db->order_by("atommeta.id");
```

or

```
$this->db->order_by("atoms.id");
```