# Magento upgrade 1.7 caused following error

Tags: sql, magento, upgrade

Admin panel works fine, but on front-end I get following error.

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'position' in order clause is ambiguous

Any idea what could this be?

Comment: It means that in a JOIN, the column position is being used but exists in 2 tables for example TABLE_A.position and TABLE_B.position and the join is using position but not specifying with table with position to use.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509798/codeigniter-column-id-in-order-clause-is-ambiguous

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but I'm a complete noob in this, if you could give me a hint how to fix this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I will need much more than what you gave me.  That error is very vague.  Are you using a custom extension?  I can tell it is an SQL statement, but there are many variables that this could be coming from.

Comment: Hmm, yes there were some extensions which I have disabled prior to upgrade process, also this is a custom theme which has wordpress integrated into it, I know :) you probably thinking ooh, I'm in a deep trouble, but yes, this is what I'm dealing with. Not sure how to show you entire error, should I copy paste? I dont know I'm very stuck on this, But thank you so much for trying to help me out, really appreciate it Vern.

Comment: You could start with checking the exception for a stack trace that should lead you to the file that should be spitting out the error to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution i came up with, Many Thanks to Vern Burton.

1. Located table eav_attribute in phpmyadmin, which was related to catalog_eav_attribute.
2. Located column position in table eav_attribute and dropped it.
3. Cleared all cache and reindexed all data, visited front page and got a new error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ‘main_table.include_in_menu’ in ‘where clause’
4. Located and opened file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php
5. Commented out following line:267 in my case ----

   ```
       ->where('main_table.is_active = ?', '1')
      // ->where('main_table.include_in_menu = ?', '1') 
       ->order('main_table.position');
   ```

I'm not really sure how esthetic this method is to fix this issue but, certainly works for me for now, If anyone has better way of fixing this I'd appreciate if you'll post your solution.

Hope this will help someone out, Cheers.

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'position' in order clause is ambiguous' in /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
```

Stack trace:
0 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

1 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)

2 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

3 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
<br>4 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT`main_ta...', Array)

5 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
<br>6 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT`main_ta...', Array)

7 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)

8 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()

9 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php(232): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()

10 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(163): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer->getFilterableAttributes()

11 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(122): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_getFilterableAttributes()

12 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_prepareLayout()

13 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(430): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))

14 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(446): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/layer_v...', 'catalog.leftnav')

15 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(238): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalog/layer_v...', 'catalog.leftnav')

16 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))

17 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))

18 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()

19 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()

20 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))

21 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(28491, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))

22 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()

23 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')

24 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

25 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

26 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

27 /chroot/home/user/my_domain.com/magento_root/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

28 {main}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebuilding your indexes?  I had a similar problem, and that fixed it.