# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'position' in order clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.6

One of my users sent me this link from our own magento website. And we have this exception, any idea how can I fix this?

http://www.theprinterdepox.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=100&q=1022&x=0&y=0

```
There has been an error processing your request


SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'position' in order clause is ambiguous

Trace:
#0 /home/theprint/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/theprint/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/theprint/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/theprint/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#4 /home/theprint/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#5 /home/theprint/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(791): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(878): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchCol(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php(291): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->getSetIds()
#8 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php(221): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer->_getSetIds()
#9 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(163): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer->getFilterableAttributes()
#10 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(122): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_getFilterableAttributes()
#11 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_prepareLayout()
#12 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(430): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#13 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(446): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalogsearch/l...', 'catalogsearch.l...')
#14 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(238): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalogsearch/l...', 'catalogsearch.l...')
#15 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#16 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#18 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(270): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#19 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php(77): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#20 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController->indexAction()
#21 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#22 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /home/theprint/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /home/theprint/public_html/www.theprinterdepo.com/index.php(55): Mage::run('printerdepo', 'website')
#26 {main}
```

**Data.php**

```
<?php
class Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const QUERY_VAR_NAME = 'q';
    const MAX_QUERY_LEN  = 200;

    /**
     * Query object
     *
     * @var Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query
     */
    protected $_query;

    /**
     * Query string
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_queryText;

    /**
     * Note messages
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_messages = array();

    /**
     * Is a maximum length cut
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isMaxLength = false;

    /**
     * Search engine model
     *
     * @var Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Engine
     */
    protected $_engine;

    /**
     * Retrieve search query parameter name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQueryParamName()
    {
        return self::QUERY_VAR_NAME;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve query model object
     *
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query
     */
    public function getQuery()
    {
        if (!$this->_query) {
            $this->_query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')
                ->loadByQuery($this->getQueryText());
            if (!$this->_query->getId()) {
                $this->_query->setQueryText($this->getQueryText());
            }
        }
        return $this->_query;
    }

    /**
     * Is a minimum query length
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isMinQueryLength()
    {
        if (Mage::helper('core/string')->strlen($this->getQueryText()) < $this->getMinQueryLength()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve search query text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQueryText()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_queryText)) {
            $this->_queryText = $this->_getRequest()->getParam($this->getQueryParamName());
            if ($this->_queryText === null) {
                $this->_queryText = '';
            } else {
                if (is_array($this->_queryText)) {
                    $this->_queryText = null;
                }
                $this->_queryText = trim($this->_queryText);
                $this->_queryText = Mage::helper('core/string')->cleanString($this->_queryText);

                if (Mage::helper('core/string')->strlen($this->_queryText) > $this->getMaxQueryLength()) {
                    $this->_queryText = Mage::helper('core/string')->substr(
                        $this->_queryText,
                        0,
                        $this->getMaxQueryLength()
                    );
                    $this->_isMaxLength = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->_queryText;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve HTML escaped search query
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEscapedQueryText()
    {
        return $this->htmlEscape($this->getQueryText());
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve suggest collection for query
     *
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Query_Collection
     */
    public function getSuggestCollection()
    {
        return $this->getQuery()->getSuggestCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve result page url and set "secure" param to avoid confirm
     * message when we submit form from secure page to unsecure
     *
     * @param   string $query
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getResultUrl($query = null)
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('catalogsearch/result', array(
            '_query' => array(self::QUERY_VAR_NAME => $query),
            '_secure' => Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve suggest url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSuggestUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('catalogsearch/ajax/suggest', array(
            '_secure' => Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve search term url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSearchTermUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('catalogsearch/term/popular');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve advanced search URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdvancedSearchUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve minimum query length
     *
     * @param mixed $store
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMinQueryLength($store = null)
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query::XML_PATH_MIN_QUERY_LENGTH, $store);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve maximum query length
     *
     * @param mixed $store
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMaxQueryLength($store = null)
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query::XML_PATH_MAX_QUERY_LENGTH, $store);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve maximum query words count for like search
     *
     * @param mixed $store
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMaxQueryWords($store = null)
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query::XML_PATH_MAX_QUERY_WORDS, $store);
    }

    /**
     * Add Note message
     *
     * @param string $message
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data
     */
    public function addNoteMessage($message)
    {
        $this->_messages[] = $message;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set Note messages
     *
     * @param array $messages
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data
     */
    public function setNoteMessages(array $messages)
    {
        $this->_messages = $messages;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Current Note messages
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getNoteMessages()
    {
        return $this->_messages;
    }

    /**
     * Check query of a warnings
     *
     * @param mixed $store
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data
     */
    public function checkNotes($store = null)
    {
        if ($this->_isMaxLength) {
            $this->addNoteMessage($this->__('Maximum Search query  length is %s. Your query was cut.', $this->getMaxQueryLength()));
        }

        $stringHelper = Mage::helper('core/string');
        /* @var $stringHelper Mage_Core_Helper_String */

        $searchType = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::XML_PATH_CATALOG_SEARCH_TYPE);
        if ($searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE ||
            $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_LIKE) {

            $wordsFull = $stringHelper->splitWords($this->getQueryText(), true);
            $wordsLike = $stringHelper->splitWords($this->getQueryText(), true, $this->getMaxQueryWords());

            if (count($wordsFull) > count($wordsLike)) {
                $wordsCut = array_diff($wordsFull, $wordsLike);

                $wordsCut = array_map(array($this, 'htmlEscape'), $wordsCut);
                $this->addNoteMessage(
                    $this->__('Maximum words count is %1$s. In your search query was cut next part: %2$s.',
                        $this->getMaxQueryWords(),
                        join(' ', $wordsCut)
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Join index array to string by separator
     * Support 2 level array gluing
     *
     * @param array $index
     * @param string $separator
     * @return string
     */
    public function prepareIndexdata($index, $separator = ' ')
    {
        $_index = array();
        foreach ($index as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                $_index[] = $value;
            }
            else {
                $_index = array_merge($_index, $value);
            }
        }
        return join($separator, $_index);
    }

    /**
     * Get current search engine resource model
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function getEngine()
    {
        if (!$this->_engine) {
            $engine = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/search/engine');

            /**
             * This needed if there already was saved in configuration some none-default engine
             * and module of that engine was disabled after that.
             * Problem is in this engine in database configuration still set.
             */
            if ($engine && Mage::getConfig()->getResourceModelClassName($engine)) {
                $model = Mage::getResourceSingleton($engine);
                if ($model && $model->test()) {
                    $this->_engine = $model;
                }
            }
            if (!$this->_engine) {
                $this->_engine = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalogsearch/fulltext_engine');
            }
        }

        return $this->_engine;
    }
}
```

**ResultController.php**

```
<?php

class Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    /**
     * Retrieve catalog session
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Session
     */
    protected function _getSession()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session');
    }
    /**
     * Display search result
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $query = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery();
        /* @var $query Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query */

        $query->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

        if ($query->getQueryText()) {
            if (Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->isMinQueryLength()) {
                $query->setId(0)
                    ->setIsActive(1)
                    ->setIsProcessed(1);
            }
            else {
                if ($query->getId()) {
                    $query->setPopularity($query->getPopularity()+1);
                }
                else {
                    $query->setPopularity(1);
                }

                if ($query->getRedirect()){
                    $query->save();
                    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($query->getRedirect());
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    $query->prepare();
                }
            }

            Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->checkNotes();

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
            $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
            $this->renderLayout();

            if (!Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->isMinQueryLength()) {
                $query->save();
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->_redirectReferer();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "position" will be in more than one joined tables, so you need to tell the query which one you want to use ie ... ORDER by table1.position ...

Comment: What does the query look like? The error seems pretty clear, you are probably joining some tables and `position` appears in more than one.

Comment: I am not joining anything, this is standard magento functionality, I never touch the magento code. :(

Comment: maybe this will help: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/196381/ if not either ask on a magento board, or hire some one with magento experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520057/magento-upgrade-1-7-caused-following-error

Comment: @BogdanBurim please red the question and the details first, even though the exception is the same, the errors are in very different context and scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't generally touch the Magento code, then an answer based around fixing the code is not going to help you greatly. So I'm going to attempt to find you a solution that does not require directly correcting the code.

As you have noticed, the error can be repeated by clicking Refurbished Printers after a search for 1022 (which matches a model code). It also appears however by clicking any category with this search.

It does not happen if you do an advanced search, eg
http://www.theprinterdepox.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=1022&sku=&price%5Bfrom%5D=&price%5Bto%5D=&free_shipping=&category=100

As a quick fix, you could redirect the problem URLs to equivalents in Advanced Search. Yes, that's a little messy, but it's better than an error message.

I would suggest that you deactivate both the products that turn up in the above Advanced Search, and then reactivate them in turn, but the products show up fine in other searches that match these products.

The only reason I can think of that Magento would fail on one search and not another is if the failing combination is cached in some way. Try clearing your cache.

Comment: I tried clearing the cache and reiindexing but it didnt work, however I am interested in the redirect, how can I do that within magento? or did you mean to do it with php.ini??

Comment: Thanks for the accept. You can redirect from within Magento, see:
http://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/url-redirection-in-magento/ which should work. If it doesn't, you'll need to add rules to your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

The error states that there are more than one table in your search query that has 'position' as a column name.

What you should do is to print out the query and analyst.

1- Open the file: /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php ( line 878)
2- From inside the method getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null) before the return statement.

```
/* remember to make this output to you only */

echo $idsSelect; /* print out the query string */

var_dump($this->_bindParams); /* query parameters values */
die;
```

3- Then post the query into your question.

Comment: I did this but I see no change in the output of the page. I checked also /var/reports, and its showing almost the same text it shows on the page, not query printed out

Comment: I see this at the top: a:5:{i:0;s:100:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'position' in order clause is ambiguous";i:1;s:3600:"#0 /home/theprint/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Comment: btw, when I added those lines, the ADMIN catalog, stopped working, I meant the search

Comment: @LuisEValencia Magento exception will override the output of this 2 line of code. add die; at the end. This should stop the script execution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Go to magentoroot/app/code/core/Mage/Catalogue/Model/Layer.php

Do a search for “public function getFilterableAttributes()”

Inside that, look for these lines:

```
->setAttributeSetFilter($setIds)
->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->setOrder('position', 'ASC');
```

Change to the following:

```
->setAttributeSetFilter($setIds)
->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
//->setOrder('position', 'ASC');
```

You’ll want to save this and place it in your local folder (/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model) so it doesn’t overwrite core Magento files. 
You may have to clear cache.

Comment: any idea why its happening only in that specific search term and not in others?

Comment: As I see that's a columns names conflict. It seems that different columns are fetched in different cases. But I do not understant how can this be dealed with search keywords. It can be dealed with products types, yes. But keyword.. Can't find logical explaination. You need just to debug it carefully if you want to find exact reason. By the way, did my post bring you at least some help? I'm not 100% sure it will fix the broblem.

Answer (score 0):

my magento knowledge no is the best, I was tried in my magento store 1.6.2.0 to search a term, change the order, and filter by a price range and works ok.

it's very strange if you don't have any extension that apply modifications to the layered navigation and you don't made any core changes. Are you using an old magento version? you was checked in the magento bugs if is a bug in your version?

probably is a lose of time, but you was tried to reindex all and delete the var/cache files?