# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I just don't know what's wrong with my code and why it produces this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `processes` inner join `bags` on `processes`.`bag_id` = `bags`.`id` where `bags`.`type` = Recyclable and date(`processes`.`created_at`) = 2018-09-18 00:00:00 order by `created_at` desc limit 1) and here's my code

```
$bag = Bagcollect::join('bags', 'bagcollects.bag_id', '=', 'bags.id')
        ->select('bags.type')
        ->where('bagcollects.bag_id', $request->input('bag_id'))
        ->first();

   //this query produce error
    $processexist = Process::join('bags', 'processes.bag_id', '=', 'bags.id')
        ->where('bags.type', $bag->type)
        ->whereDate('processes.created_at', Carbon::today())
        ->latest()
        ->first();
```

Comment: you have created_at column in multiple tables (which are being joined here). You need to specify a specific alias/table name to use a particular created_at column for order by

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter: Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509798/codeigniter-column-id-in-order-clause-is-ambiguous)

Comment: ambiguous column error can only point to `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `ON` (when joining), `HAVING`, `GROUP BY` clauses to add to @MadhurBhaiya 's comment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to specify, in `latest()` the full column. `latest('process.created_at')` or instead of using `latest()` use a custom orderBy.

Answer (score 6):

Thats because you are querying the 'created_at' column from two tables. You have to specify wich colums you need, for example:

```
$processexist = Process::join('bags', 'processes.bag_id', '=', 'bags.id')
        ->select('bags.column1', 'bags.columns2')
        ->where('bags.type', $bag->type)
        ->whereDate('processes.created_at', Carbon::today())
        ->latest()
        ->first();
```