# How to order by the column which has the same column name in two tables after union two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

These are the two tables:

```
Create table If Not Exists Customers (Id int, Name varchar(255));
Create table If Not Exists Orders (Id int, CustomerId int);
insert into Customers (Id, Name) values ('1', 'Joe');
insert into Customers (Id, Name) values ('2', 'Henry');
insert into Customers (Id, Name) values ('3', 'Sam');
insert into Customers (Id, Name) values ('4', 'Max');
insert into Orders (Id, CustomerId) values ('1', '3');
insert into Orders (Id, CustomerId) values ('2', '1');
insert into Orders (Id, CustomerId) values ('3', '5');
insert into Orders (Id, CustomerId) values ('4', '6');
```

And I union the left join and right join of the two tables:

```
select *
from customers as c
left join orders as o
on c.id = o.customerid

union

select *
from customers as c
right join orders as o
on c.id = o.customerid;
```

But I wanna order the result set by the id from table customers:

```
select
*
from
customers as c
left join
orders as o
on
c.id = o.customerid

union

select
*
from
customers as c
right join
orders as o
on
c.id = o.customerid
order by
c.id;
```

But the MySQL response is "Error Code: 1250. Table 'c' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause". So I change the code into:

```
select
*
from
customers as c
left join
orders as o
on
c.id = o.customerid

union

select
*
from
customers as c
right join
orders as o
on
c.id = o.customerid
order by
id;
```

But the MySQL response is "Error Code: 1052. Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous".

I really understand the two responses but I also want to know how to order by id from customers after the union?

Comment: Maybe this here is your solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509798/codeigniter-column-id-in-order-clause-is-ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509798/codeigniter-column-id-in-order-clause-is-ambiguous)

Comment: What results do you want?  I see no reason for a `union` with this data.  Why would you have invalid customer ids in the `order`s data?  Your data model appears to be messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need a global ordering by making the current query a subquery as by aliasing id columns individually :

```
select *
  from
  (
   select c.id as c_id, c.name, o.id as o_id, o.CustomerId
     from customers as c
     left join orders as o
       on c.id = o.customerid
    union    
   select c.id as c_id, c.name, o.id as o_id, o.CustomerId
     from customers as c
    right join orders as o
       on c.id = o.customerid    
  ) q
 order by q.c_id
```

Comment: I think doing like this may be more simple: `select name, customerid, c.id as c_id, o.id as o_id
from customers as c
left join orders as o
on c.id = o.customerid
union
select name, customerid, c.id as c_id, o.id as o_id
from customers as c
right join orders as o
on c.id = o.customerid
order by c_id;`  Just rename the two columns which has the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need in this:

```
(
select c.id c_id, c.name, o.id o_id
from Customers as c
left join Orders as o on c.id = o.customerid
)
union
(
select o.customerid, c.name, o.id
from Customers as c
right join Orders as o on c.id = o.customerid
)
order by c_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78dd69d62148f551cd8be805d6687227)

Comment: Oh sorry to say this doesn't work. Adding "()" does the same work as no "()".

Comment: @TingweiMa It seems I have not understood your task correctly... look now.